# Null Space of an Identity Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces and let $I: V \to V$ be the identity transformation.

In *Linear Algebra* by Friedberg, Insel and Spence, it states that the nullspace of an identity transformation is $\{0\}$, but I'm having a hard time seeing why, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the null space of $I$. Then, $N=\{v\in V|I(v)=0\}$. Now, note that $0=I(v)=v\iff v =0$. Hence, $N=\{0\}$.

Comment: In words, if {0} wasn't the null-space, then there would be another vector which is not 0 for which I(v)=0 -- but since $v\not=0$, this would mean in particular that I was not the identity. Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

It becomes very clear since you know that the Identity transformation by definition, maps vectors back to themselves ($I(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}$).

Basically if you wanted to find the solutions that map to $\vec{0}$, you might consider two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ such that $I(x) = \vec{0}$ and $I(y) = \vec{0}$, while $\vec{x} \neq \vec{y}$ simultaneously, which becomes immediately apparent is impossible.

A simple note is that $I$ is trivially injective. Thus it follows its nullspace is $\{\vec{0}\}$

Answer (score 0):

The null-space of a linear transformation is all vectors that are sent to zero by that transformation. The identity transformation sends every vector to itself. Thus the only vector sent to zero by the identity transformation is the zero vector. Thus the null-space of the identity transformation is $\{0\}$.